# Выберите корректный вариант. Вашего варианта нет среди допустимых значений. Django python

Tags: python, django

при вводе правильного значения в `input`, выводит `Выберите корректный вариант. Вашего варианта нет среди допустимых значений`
ошибка в том, что при вводе надо указать поле `pk` для модели `Service` и тогда сохраняется модель. А как сделать, чтобы при записи формы учитывалось сравнение именно по полю `name`?

**models**

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, unique=True, verbose_name='Наименования услуги')
    used = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms**

```
class SettingDeviceAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['name']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autocomplete': 'off'}),
        }

    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if re.match(r'\d', name):
            raise ValidationError('Название не должно начинаться с цифры')
        if not name[0].isupper():
            raise ValidationError('Название не должно начинаться с маленькой буквы')
        return name
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как сформирована форма? логику, бы, для нее добавить. Может передаете с формы не верные данные. Но это гадание, код бы

Comment: добавил форму, можете посомтреть